# Asynchronous function findOne returns "undefined"

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I created a function to check if in my database a user exists according to the `sub` parameter.
I would like my function to give me a `true` or `false` value.

**Front-end**:

```
......
async function exist(sub) {
  const result = await InfoDataService.get(sub)
  alert(result.sub);
 }      
......
```

**Controller**:

```
// Find a User with sub
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
  const sub = req.params.sub;
  

  User.findOne({sub})
  .then(data => {
    res.send(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Error retrieving User with id=" +sub 
    });
  });
};
```

**Route**:

```
module.exports = app => {
  const users = require("../controllers/user.controller.js");

  const router = require("express").Router();


  // Retrieve
  router.get("/:sub", users.findOne);


  app.use('/api/users', router);
};
```

**InfoDataService**:

```
import http from "../http-common.js";


const get = sub => {
  return http.get(`/users/${sub}`);
};

export default {
  get,
};
```

**http-common**:

```
import axios from "axios";


    export default axios.create({
      method: 'GET',
      baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api",
      
    });
```

If instead of `result.sub` I use only `result` I can retrieve the object, but if I try to access the `.sub` property I get "undefined".

I noticed another thing that is probably related: the path for post is `api/users`, while for get it is `api/users/:sub`.
Checking the network I found that the asynchronous function makes the request to `api/users/undefined`. Where would the error be?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if `User.findOne({sub})` is correct, should maybe rather be a where clause there? `{ where: sub}`

Comment: I also knew it, but if I write where: sub I have errors everywhere. The path is always users / undefined for the asynchronous function and in addition I have "error connection refused" for all other communications with the API